# Docker Compose watch for changes inside the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, web-development-server

The `watch` command allows to automatically update files in the container as they are changed on the host machine. [1](https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/)

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    ...
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: .
          target: /var/www
```

Am I correct in saying that it doesn't work the other way around: changes in `target` directory in the container will **not** be reflected in the `path` on the host machine?

E.g., if I wanted to create logs files inside the container and write them to the project directory on my host machine, would I have to bind `volume`?

Comment: Yes, the changes made to the file within the container do not sync back to the host. And any changes made to the file within the container will be overwritten when some other changes are made to the file in the host. Using a volume would work for data created within the container to be available on the host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you are right. **At this moment, `sync` is 1-way**: changes in the host system will be reflected in the container, but not the other way round.

The [sync documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/#sync) mentions that **files are synced from host to container** and that, for most development cases, this can be used instead of bind mounts.

However, it also says it [does not replace bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/#compose-watch-versus-bind-mounts), so if you need changes inside the container to be propagated back to the host, you would need to use bind mounts.